# Display search results on the same page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am trying to create a Wordpress page which contains a Search form, but I can't display the search results on the same page. I've seen that I should include a Wordpress loop in my php file, but I can't figure out how.

Here is my search form:

```
<form id="searchform" action="../search4.php" method="post"><input id="Cref" style="height: 20px; width: 140px;" name="Cref" type="text" value="" />

<input id="submit" name="search" type="submit" value="Search" />

</form>
```

The search4.php file is this one:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username='root';
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username, Null, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}  


            if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
               $Cref = addslashes ($_POST['Cref']);
                }else {
               $Cref = $_POST['Cref'];
              }

session_start();

$results="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CRF LIKE CONCAT ('%', $Cref, '%')";   


$resultSet = $mysqli->query($results);
$numRows = $resultSet->num_rows;

if ($numRows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_object()) {
        echo "{$row->CRF} {$row->Name} {$row->Description}  <br>";
    }}
else
   {
   echo "No Results";}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:

**Custom form:**

```
<form role="search" method="GET" id="searchform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="search">

    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**On the page I wanted the search results:**

I did a `WP_query` like on the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
and changed the `$args` to:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) ){
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'paged'           => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'  => 16, //or any number
        'post_type'       => 'post', //or your custom post type if needed
        's'               => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ]
    );
}
```